# Convert binary string to bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I have a string that is made up of byte values 0-255. I need to convert it to a bytearray. *I do not want* to transform range 128-255 to utf-8 – in fact, the string is already encoded in utf-8.

How the heck do I get around the frustrating 'not in 0-128 range' error?

```
>>> string.encode('ascii')
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

```
>>> bytearray(string, 'ascii')
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: How did you end up with a "string" that's "already encoded in utf-8"? If it's already encoded, it should have type `bytes` rather than `str`. It sounds as though you need to fix the code that's producing `string` in the first place. (Or are you on Python 2?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `latin-1` codec (aka `latin_1`, `iso-8859-1`, `iso8859-1`, `8859`, `cp819`, `latin`, `latin1`, and `L1`) [is a 1-to-1 encoding encoding each Unicode ordinal from 0 to 255 to an equivalent byte value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode). Assuming your string contains no ordinals above 255, it should work for your purposes.

Comment: Gosh, that was frustrating. Thanks, it's working. Is there a list of these 'codecs' somewhere?

Comment: H! https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html look at "Standard Encodings" paragraph

Comment: @Codesmith: [Yes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings), though the unique features of `latin-1` aren't there; there is a note on it [in a different section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode).

Answer (score -2):

The following code works for me and create a array of bytes:

```
In [1]: import array

In [2]: string="ABCDą"

In [3]: array.array('B',string.encode('utf-8'))
Out[3]: array('B', [65, 66, 67, 68, 196, 133])
```

Comment: The OP explicitly said "I DO NOT WANT to transform range 128-255 to utf-8". And there is no need for the `array` module for simple arrays of bytes; `bytes` (Python 3) and `bytearray` (both Python 2 and 3) are already arrays of bytes.